# Why sum of odd numbers from 1 to the number entered doesn't match what was expected?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OddSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num;
        int i = 1;
        int sum = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        num = input.nextInt();
        input.close();

        while (i<=num) {
            i += 2;
            sum +=i;
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of odd numbers between 1 and" + num + "is: "     + sum);
    }
}
```

I wrote this code to sum up the odd numbers from 1 to a number entered.
Now, when I entered 8, I got the output as 24, against the desired output 16.
Can you tell me what went wrong?

Comment: Well, you should add to sum before you increment i.

Comment: `i += 2;` should be after `sum += i;` Use a `for` loop instead though.

Comment: @4castle, usage of loops is an overkill, it can be calculated easily with a formula...

Comment: Thanks. I did the for loop already. Was stuck at while.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing the variable before performing summation .

```
while (i<=num) {
      sum +=i;
      i += 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `i` to `sum` before adding to 2 to `i`. Thus, once `i` goes past `num`, the `while` loop will no longer execute.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OddSum {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num;
    int i = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    num = input.nextInt();
    input.close();

    while (i<=num) {

        // add i to sum before adding 2 to i
        sum += i;
        i += 2;

    }
    System.out.println("The sum of odd numbers between 1 and" + num + "is: "     + sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets debug the code together:

after taking the number it would go to `i<=num` that while condition. Great, Then instead of getting sum it would `+` again 2 which cause `3`. So what's happen? First case, `1` is not added before and first iteration value `1` is lose. That means whenever, you enter the loop. It goes increases before adding the previous value. So, rewrite the code this way:

```
while (i<=num) {
  sum +=i;
  i += 2;
}
```

You may use `for` instead:

```
 for(int i=1;i<=num;i+=2){
      sum +=i;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're incrementing `i` **before** you sum it, instead of **afterwards**:

```
while (i <= num) {
    sum +=i;
    i += 2;
}
```

It's worth noting, though, that these kind of issues, where the loop variable is incremented by a constant, are often more convenient to write with a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i += 2) {
    sum += i;
}
```

Or better yet, if you're using Java 8, by collecting a stream:

```
int sum = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, num).filter(i -> i % 2 != 0).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the result for your example with `N = 8` gives `24` is because when `i` reaches value `7`, the loop is continued and is added the value `9` to your `sum` too and you forget to add the first odd number: `1`, because you start over from adding directly `3` to your `sum`.
You can either switch the statements between each other, either use a `for` loop instead of `while`:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= num; i += 2) {
      sum += i;
   }
```